# jQuery not returns actual select option attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI select widget.

Widget may be fully re-initialized after Ajax call that returns html of select, on which afterwords widget is applied.

The problem is that after widget initialization the actual chosen select option is not selected.

When debugging I'm getting following outputs from Chrome DevTools console:

```
> thisWidget.element
[<select name=​"main.model" id=​"ui-id-297" style=​"display:​ none;​">​<option selected=​"selected" value>​ Choose ​</option>​<option value=​"express">​ Express ​</option>​</select>​]

> thisWidget.element.find('option')
[<option selected=​"selected" value>​ Choose ​</option>​, <option value=​"express">​ Express ​</option>​]

> thisWidget.element.find('option:selected')
[]

> thisWidget.element.find("option[value='']")
[<option selected=​"selected" value>​ Choose ​</option>​]

> thisWidget.element.find("option[value='']:selected")
[]
```

As I see it the html on which widget is initialized is correct, but the option with empty value is not selected despite that it should be.

Why am I getting this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why.

I was setting select value before widget was destroyed and re-initialized.

So events were occuring like this:

```
// getting re-rendered html select through ajax call
mySelect.val('foo') // setting the value of select which in fact may not have option with such value
// ...then destroy event occurs
// ... and then widget is reinitiazlied
```

So probably interlieving with undestroyed widget and value setting (`mySelect.val('foo')`) was the cause of such behavior.